# text-overflow ellipsis with no text and Safari

Tags: css, safari, overflow, ellipsis

I have a content that is not text (dots), and I need that when this content exceeds its container div, the ellipsis comes out.
In Chrome and FF the ellipsis is displayed. But not in Safari (14.1).

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 110px;
}
span {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display:inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>  
  <span></span>  
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/tribaldo/pen/ZEerXzB

Thank you.

Comment: Hey @Tribaldo, did u had any luck with this issue?